# Detect if class is UIView subclass or UIView exactly

Tags: swift, uiview

Is there a method to figure out the difference between UIView subclass or UIView class?

Like:

```
func(UITableView) = false
func(UIView) = true
```

Comment: Do you mean `type(of: yourView) == UIView.self`?

Comment: This is kinda suspicious, your code shouldn't care about concrete classes like this.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica, I'm using framework with not accessible for me UIView's subclass and need to find it in subviews somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `type(of:)` to get the type of a variable, then compare that to `UIView.self` to check if they are an exact match using the equality operators (`==` and `!=`).

```
extension UIView {
    var isCustomView: Bool {
        type(of: self) != UIView.self
    }
}

class MyCustomView: UIView {}

UIView().isCustomView // false
MyCustomView().isCustomView // true
```